# how to pass class in checkbox using cakephp form

Tags: cakephp

i am using below code:-

```
echo $this->Form->input('my_radio',array(
    'label' =>false,
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'class'=>'checkbox12',
    'div'=>false,
    'selected' => array_keys($sub_cat_name1),
    'options' => $parent_cat_detail1
));
```

i did false the div but still the 'checkbox12' is adding to div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not in the class , is in the mutiple value , you should put it true not checkbox :

```
echo $this->Form->input('my_radio',array(
    'label' =>false,
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => true,
    'class'=>'checkbox12',
    'selected' => array_keys($sub_cat_name1),
    'options' => $parent_cat_detail1
));
```

Comment: yes this should work according to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#generating-specific-types-of-inputs